# Populate Pandas dataframe with group_by calculations made in Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have created a dataframe from a dictionary as follows:

`my_dict = {'VehicleType':['Truck','Car','Truck','Car','Car'],'Colour':['Green','Green','Black','Yellow','Green'],'Year':[2002,2014,1975,1987,1987],'Frequency': [0,0,0,0,0]}`

`df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)`

So my dataframe df currently looks like this:

```
  VehicleType  Colour  Year  Frequency
0       Truck   Green  2002          0
1         Car   Green  2014          0
2       Truck   Black  1975          0
3         Car  Yellow  1987          0
4         Car   Green  1987          0
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
  VehicleType  Colour  Year  Frequency
0       Truck   Green  2002          1
1         Car   Green  2014          2
2       Truck   Black  1975          1
3         Car  Yellow  1987          1
4         Car   Green  1987          2
```

i.e., the Frequency column should represent the totals of VehicleType AND Colour combinations (but leaving out the Year column). So in row 4 for example, the 2 in the Frequency column tells you that there are a total of 2 rows with the combination of 'Car' and 'Green'.

This is essentially a 'Count' with 'Group By' calculation, and Pandas provides a way to do the calculation as follows:

`grp_by_series = df.groupby(['VehicleType', 'Colour']).size()`

`grp_by_series`

```
VehicleType  Colour
Car          Green     2
             Yellow    1
Truck        Black     1
             Green     1
dtype: int64
```

What I'd like to do next is to extract the calculated group_by values from the Panda series and put them into the Frequency column of the Pandas dataframe. I've tried various approaches but without success.

The example I've given is hugely simplified - the dataframes I'm using are derived from genomic data and have hundreds of millions of rows, and will have several frequency columns based on various combinations of other columns, so ideally I need a solution which is fast and scales well.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on a good path. You can continue like this:

```
grp_by_series=grp_by_series.reset_index()

res=df[['VehicleType', 'Colour']].merge(grp_by_series, how='left')

df['Frequency'] =  res[0]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  VehicleType  Colour  Year  Frequency
0       Truck   Green  2002          1
1         Car   Green  2014          2
2       Truck   Black  1975          1
3         Car  Yellow  1987          1
4         Car   Green  1987          2
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. I'll look into the Pandas documentation to get a handle on what exactly is going on with your solution, but it has certainly solved the issue for me now. Cheers!

Comment: Happy to help!
Can you please accept the answer, so that it will be removed from 'unanswered' queue?
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I think a .transform() does what you want:

```
df['Frequency'] = df.groupby(['VehicleType', 'Colour'])['Year'].transform('count')
```

Comment: I think this is short and nice answer `df['Frequency'] = df.groupby(['VehicleType', 'Colour'])['Year'].transform('count')`.

Comment: @Karn I couldn't get D.Bakhuis's suggestion to work, so I was going to come back to it later and give it a more thorough examination. However, you seem to have fixed the issue with this answer - there's a missing bracket ")" after the 'Colour'].

I tried with your edit, and it works as well. Both answers so far now work correctly, so I'll apply them both to the much larger dataframe I have in my code and see which performs better, and I'll leave a comment reflecting my findings. Thanks for your help too!

Comment: @D. Bakhuis - as per Karn Kumar's comment, I believe there's a bracket missing in your answer? I've tried your (edited) solution on the dataframe example I described in this question, and it works now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PhilipOBrien, yes .. i fixed that, it should work for you.

Comment: Ah, I see it now that I indeed forgot the closing bracket. Glad it all worked out :-)